# Weekday last 3 days records

Tags: mysql, select, intervals

I have a query. In the last 3 days(weekday) I want to list the ones without the data.

service table:                records1:

```
---------------------    ---------------------------------------    
|   id   |   name   |    |   id   |    service_id |     date   |
|-------------------|    |-------------------------------------|
|   1    |   a      |    |   1    |        1      | 2019-03-26 |  
|   2    |   ab     |    |   2    |        3      | 2019-03-25 |
|   3    |   ac     |    |   3    |        6      | 2019-03-24 | (weekend)          
|   4    |   ad     |    |   4    |        4      | 2019-03-26 |
|   5    |   af     |    ---------------------------------------
|   6    |   ah     |
---------------------


Select s.id, s.name from service s 
where s.id not in (select service_id from records1 where date(dateff) >     DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) and WEEKDAY(curdate()) in (0,1,2,3,4) )
and WEEKDAY(curdate()) in (0,1,2,3,4)
```

I need: For example today is Tuesday(2019-03-26). It will list the names If there is no data the last 3 days(Tuesday,Monday,Friday) in the table.

Table:

```
---------------------     
|   name |   name   |    
|-------------------|  
|   1    |   a      |   
|   3    |   ac     |              
|   4    |   ad     | 
---------------------
```

Comment: There's no phone in the data set. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bwobAMFSchEDq6AxbHaL7/0

```
SELECT 
    s.id,
    s.name,                   
    COUNT(DISTINCT r.id)
FROM service s
LEFT JOIN records1 r
ON date(r.dateff) >= @today - INTERVAL @period DAY
   AND r.service_id = s.id
   AND WEEKDAY(r.dateff) in (0,1,2,3,4)
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 
      @today := DATE('2019-03-26'), 
      @weekDay := WEEKDAY(@today), 
      @period := IF(@weekDay IN (2,3,4),3, IF(@weekDay IN (0,1,6), 5, 4))
) vars
GROUP BY s.id, s.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT r.id) = 0
```